# Switching X and Y axis on 3D surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, surface

I'm trying to plot a surface of rolling correlations - 10 day through to 200 day.

I have a dataframe similar to:

```
st = {'10': [-0.2,0.4,0.1], '20': [0.6,0.3,0], '30': [-0.4,0.6,0.2], '40': [0.1,0.2,0.4]}
st = pd.DataFrame(data=st)
st.index = pd.date_range("20200101", periods=3)
st

            10   20   30  40
2020-01-01 -0.2  0.6 -0.4 0.1
2020-01-02  0.4  0.3  0.6 0.2
2020-01-03  0.1  0.0  0.2 0.4
```

I'm using the code below to get the following output:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = st.columns
y = np.arange(0,len(st),1)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = st

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

dates = st.index

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(10,210,10))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(y)
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(dates);
```

[image]

However, the x and y axis are reversed. I'm trying to get the dates along the x axis and the rolling correlations on the y axis.

I tried this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y = np.meshgrid(st.index, st.columns)

z = st

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

dates = st.index

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(10,210,10))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(y)
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(dates);
```

But I get the following error:

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Can anyone help out with where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you simply change the viewing angle?